# need help with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$(1-\sqrt3i)(1-i)^2 + 1 + \sqrt3i = ?$

My result is: $-2i - 2\sqrt3 + 1 + \sqrt3i$

Is this the right result or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct, but the answer is still incomplete. The standard form for complex numbers is $a+bi$, so you should combine the real and the imaginary terms in the answer you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

$$(1-i\sqrt3)(1-i)^2+1+i\sqrt3=(1-i\sqrt3)(-2i)+1+i\sqrt3=$$

$$=-2\sqrt3-2i+1+i\sqrt3=(1-2\sqrt3)+(\sqrt3-2)i$$

Comment: @MJD; how can it "engage"(?) if the work isn't shown? And the answer does *answer* the OP's question: his solution is wrong. I show him the different steps taken, so that he can check his own work.

Comment: Hmmm...and after writing nicely the OP's question I can see now his solution is right, after all. And @MJD, why did you delete your comment to my answer explaining your downvote?

Comment: I decided that my previous practice of downvoting without leaving explanatory comments was better, since it invariably leads to unproductive arguments like this one.

Comment: @MJD "Unproductive" meaning that someone doesn't agree with you? Oh, well: I see.

Comment: My pleasure, @Kurama